# Mat Form Field Angular: Como manter o tamanho original da fonte quando o form-field é focado?

Tags: css, angular-material

Estou usando [Angular Material form field](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples) com input. Quando eu clico no meu form field, minha label tem a font-size diminuida.

Como posso manter o tamanho original da minha label quando o form field possui foco?

Eu encontrei a classe responsável por elevar a label e diminuir o seu tamanho:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label {
    transform: translateY(-1.1em) scale(0.75);
}
```

Se eu coloco `scale(1.00)` minha fonte permanece com o tamanho original, porém minha borda é colapsada conforme imagem:

[image]

Comment: Você vai precisar aumentar o tamanho do `mat-form-field-outline-gap` dentro do `mat-form-field-outline-thick`, se você olhar, ele possui um width fixo, deve ser de acordo com o tamanho do texto, você precisa sobreescrever esse width fixo de acordo com o tamanho do label, por padrão ele é calculado apra se encaixar no label com scale

Comment: @AndréMonteiro sim, o problema é que não dá pra colocar um width fixo porque cada campo tem um tamanho específico. Eu consegui um workaround, vou postar como fiz em breve

Comment: É eu pensei em uma gambiarra, ao carregar a página, pega o tamanho dos labels e definir esse width fixo, por que o que o form faz hoje é isso, mas calculando de acordo com o scale

Comment: Entendo, a minha também foi uma "gambiarra" mas feita através do css, me atende melhor pois vou usar o input dessa forma em diversos componentes diferentes. Vou postar em breve caso alguém precisar. É uma pena que o material design angular não propõe uma forma de contornar o tamanho do font-size da label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra quem precisar, consegui uma solução de contorno.

**Meu objetivo** 
Manter o `font-size: 14px` da `label` estando ou não com focus.

**O problema** 
O componente [Material Form Field](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview) segue a especificação do Material Design, onde indica que o tamanho da label deve ser reduzido ao entrar na posição elevada. Como o gap é calculado programaticamente através do javascript ([vide código responsável pelo cálculo do gap](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/form-field/form-field.ts#L590)), ao alterar o `scale` para ter o tamanho original da fonte, a borda entra em colapso com a label, conforme demonstrado na pergunta.

**Solução de contorno**

Define o tamanho da fonte do `mat-form-field` para o tamanho desejado:

```
mat-form-field {
  font-size: 14px!important;
}
```

Nega o tamanho calculado pela biblioteca para ocupar toda a borda do topo:

```
.mat-form-field-outline-gap {
   width: 0!important;
}
```

Sobrescreve a classe que diminui o tamanho da fonte ao flutuar, indicando que agora a fonte deve ter o mesmo tamanho ao elevar e realiza ajustes de posição na função `translateY()`:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-label {
  transform: translateY(-1.7em) scale(1)!important;
}
```

Define um `background-color` para a mat-label bem como um espaçamento entre as laterais, tornando ela a responsável por quebrar o "gap" definido pela biblioteca:

```
mat-form-field mat-label  {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

**Resultados**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]